# adding row generated inside a loop to a new data frame

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have a `for` loop to iterate through every row of a data frame. Now, when certain expressions match, I want to add the matching row to a new data frame.

This is what I have done:

```
dfWithSand3 = pd.DataFrame()
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['embarked'] == 'S' and row['pclass'] == 3:
        dfWithSand3.append(row)
print(dfWithSand3)
```

Here, `pd` is `pandas` and `df` is the data frame.

Whenever the expression below is `True` I want to add the row to the data frame `dfWithSand3`.

```
if row['embarked'] == 'S' and row['pclass'] == 3:
```

Right now the value of the data frame `dfWithSand3` is:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

Below is what a possible `row` value could look like

```
Unnamed: 0     600
survived         0
pclass           3
sex           male
age             42
sibsp            0
parch            0
fare          7.55
embarked         S
```

I don't know if row represents a data frame or not.

Also, how would I add row to the new data frame I have created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you can do it this way:

```
dfWithSand3  = df.loc[(df.embarked == 'S') & (df.pclass == 3)].copy()
```

or if you don't want to preserve original index values:

```
dfWithSand3  = df.loc[(df.embarked == 'S') & (df.pclass == 3)].reset_index().copy()
```

Comment: So I would not need any loops or anything extra?

Comment: @Cybercop, yes, we want to avoid loops, when using Pandas/Numpy/scipy

Comment: well, you want to let pandas do it's own looping so it can optimize further then a `for` loop in python.

Comment: I dont want to ask a separate question for this so I would like to ask here. How do I check for NaN values or empty values? when i try lets say `df.loc[(df.embarked == '') & (df.pclass == 3)].copy()` or simply `df.loc[(df.embarked == np.NaN)` doesn't seem to work

Comment: @Cybercop, please check `pd.isnull()` method and read how to deal with [missing data](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/cookbook.html#missing-data)